# Add Class on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and I'd like it so once somebody clicks on the textarea (or presses f (keycode 70)), everything else fades out and it adds the class focus to the body.

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to what @Swadq said, to answer the rest of your question:

```
//Listen for the 'f' key to be pressed
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 70) {
    $('#textarea').focus();
  }
});
$('#textarea').focus(function() {
  $(body).addClass('focus');
});
```

For the fading bit, refer to this: http://buildinternet.com/2009/08/lights-out-dimmingcovering-background-content-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').focus(function() {
     $(this).addClass('focusClass');
});
```